# make button disapear when clicked even when visited next time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a problem i am making a website with a button on it. 
The problem is that i only want this pressed once by the user who visits the site. 
So when ever the user refreshes or comes back it isn't possible to press it again.

I think i should use a combination of PHP with AJAX but unfortunally i am not good enough to get it together. In the hope somebody here can push me in the right direction :)

the html code:

```
    <form action="" method="POST">

    <input id="banana_button" type="submit" name="button_press" value="Add banana's!">
</form>
```

the javascript:

```
$('input[name="button_press"').click(function(){

        $('#banana_counter_text').append($banana+1);
        $(this).attr('disabled',true).css('width','180px').attr('value','thanks for adding a banana');
    });
```

What i want to get is that when they pressed the button next time they visit they won't see the button. 
Is it possible and how could i best do this. I hope you guys can help me

**Update:**

Well i was trying the last few days to resolve this problem and i got it working. 
I am using a session_cookie with a custom name. Everytime the site is loaded it checks if that cookie is available if not than it wil show the button. Else it will delete the whole button.

the code looks like this:

PHP

```
//this is what checks everytime if the cookie is set
    if (isset($_COOKIE['banana_added'])) {
        //code for disabling the button 
    }

//this is what makes the cookie and checks if the submit button is pressed. 
//because people where wondering how the data is stored. It is just a simple XML file
    if(isset($_POST['buttonsubmit'])){
        /*when submit is pressed */
        session_name("banana_added");
        session_start();
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('../banana.xml');
        $prev_count = $xml->banana_count;
        $new_count = $prev_count +$_POST['buttonsubmit'];
        echo $prev_count;
        echo $new_count;
        $xml->banana_count = $new_count;
        file_put_contents('../banana.xml', $xml->asXML());
        header("location:../landing.php");
```

Thank you all for your help. I don't know how i can close this thread ? 
**This is the solution for this particular problem**

Comment: are users only able to click if they are logged in or such?

Comment: You have PHP as one of the tags.  Are you using PHP to manage your data (store it in a database, for example)?  The type of feature you're looking for is a "one-time" feature, where it appears once then disables itself once the user provides input.

Comment: Easy solution is to store a cookie and hide the button if the cookie is present. This doesn't prevent people from "clearing cookie cache" and resubmitting. For more explicit control you'll need a server side solution which bring in a whole lot of complexity identifying and storing 'has visited' users.

Comment: how are you checking whether it is a first visit, or a revisit?

Comment: I will submit to a database or such how often the button is pressed. There is no login needed for the button to be pressed. I was trying to put it in a cookie but don't really know how to combine this al so the button will be invissible because i am also using javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i was trying the last few days to resolve this problem and i got it working. I am using a session_cookie with a custom name. Everytime the site is loaded it checks if that cookie is available if not than it wil show the button. Else it will delete the whole button.

the code looks like this:

```
PHP

//this is what checks everytime if the cookie is set
    if (isset($_COOKIE['banana_added'])) {
        //code for disabling the button 
    }

//this is what makes the cookie and checks if the submit button is pressed. 
//because people where wondering how the data is stored. It is just a simple XML file
    if(isset($_POST['buttonsubmit'])){
        /*when submit is pressed */
        session_name("banana_added");
        session_start();
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('../banana.xml');
        $prev_count = $xml->banana_count;
        $new_count = $prev_count +$_POST['buttonsubmit'];
        echo $prev_count;
        echo $new_count;
        $xml->banana_count = $new_count;
        file_put_contents('../banana.xml', $xml->asXML());
        header("location:../landing.php");
```

Thank you all for your help. 
This is the solution for this particular problem

Answer (score 0):

In order to remember that change you should either put that value in COOKIE/SESSION or in DATABASE. The second variant ofcourse is preferd.
So lets say in example you have table called buttons and in it you have a column 'checked' with type tinyint (accepting values 0 and 1) and default value of 0.

In your html you should do this:

```
<button <?php ($thisButtonQuery->checked == 'checked')? 'disabled' : '';?>>button text </button>
```

Regards and i hope i resolved your roblem! :)

Comment: I never used databases so it is kinda hard for me to set this up. Is There maybe a way you can explain by using a cookie or such ?